# Unable to hit the Servlet page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Good Day,

I have just configured the tomcat and using the java servlet pages. I'm new with this and unable to hit the index page successfully but if I directly tried to hit the form action and passed the defined param then I could see the results. Please guide me if I'm missing something.

**JSP - Code**

```
 <div align="center" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <form action="CrunchifyServlet">
        Please enter your Username:  <input type="text" name="username" size="20px"> <br>
        Please enter your Password:  <input type="text" name="password" size="20px"> <br><br>
        Please enter your Age:  <input type="text" name="age" size="20px"> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form> 
</div>
```

**Java - Code**

```
 public class HelloCrunchify extends HttpServlet {
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // reading the user input
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println (
                  "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" +" +
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n" +
                  "<html> \n" +
                    "<head> \n" +
                      "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; " +
                        "charset=ISO-8859-1\"> \n" +
                      "<title> Crunchify.com JSP Servlet Example  </title> \n" +
                    "</head> \n" +
                    "<body> <div align='center'> \n" +
                      "<style= \"font-size=\"12px\" color='black'\"" + "\">" +
                        "Username: " + username + " <br> " + 
                        "Password: " + password + " <br> " +
                        "Age: " + age +
                    "</font></body> \n" +
                  "</html>" 
                );      
        }
```

}

**web.xml**

```
   <display-name>CrunchifyJSPServletExample</display-name>
   <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.crunchify.jsp.servlet.HelloCrunchify</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/CrunchifyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

[image: Project Explorer]

and if i tried to hit this `localhost:9080/CrunchifyJSPServletExample/Crunchify.jsp`I'm getting HTTP Status 404.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to see the jsp page ? Or its just that you are not able to submit it ?

Comment: @SacJn no I'm just receiving the Http status - 404. Just to cross checked does the tomcat is working or not I directly submit the form with defined params and saw the results. but I'm unable to see my jsp page.

Comment: Then its the problem with name and path of your jsp page. Can you confirm it ?

Comment: Here it is http://localhost:9080/CrunchifyJSPServletExample/Crunchify.jsp

Comment: Do I need to update the web.xml of tomcat? do I need to add teh servlet tags over there ?

Comment: with given information, i guess the name is not correct in your url `Crunchify.jsp`.Can you show the file structure of your project?everything shown seems coorect here.Either you have nt put your jsp in web-content folder or you are messing something else.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta I have updated my post with project explorer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take out your jsp from `WEB-INF` and put it directly under `WebContent` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your web.xml and reading your comment you are using  Crunchify.jsp to post data ,but servlet container is unable to find Crunchify.jsp in proper folder in the war, so you are getting this error 404, what you need to do is place  Crunchify.jsp in same folder as index.jsp 
[image]

As display in above image put Crunchify.jsp like WebPages -->  Crunchify.jsp
now if you invoke `http://localhost:9080/CrunchifyJSPServletExample/Crunchify.jsp` should work fine

Comment: please see the updated post. I have attached the project explorer

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are using the correct context path `CrunchifyJSPServletExample`.
Typically it will be the generated war file name if you are deploying to Tomcat manually or if you use the tomcat configured in eclipse you can specify the path in the Modules tab.

Comment: Thanks for you response there is nothing wrong with the link I Tried to hit this http://localhost:9080/CrunchifyJSPServletExample/CrunchifyServlet?username=crunchify&password=Password, I can successfully see the context written in java class which I'm printing thru PrintWriter

Comment: OK. I just tried with you code in my machine and was able to load the jsp page successfully and form submission works fine. Is your jsp page located under webapps folder?

Comment: here in my machine it's in WebContent/WEB-INF.

Comment: Put your jsp file in Web-Content folder and you will be good.

Comment: @PrinceManiGupta oh my God.. it's working fine now. please add your answer so that I have mark it as done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: glad it helped.Added answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Try it. Change Java Code.

Before:

```
protected void **doGet**(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

After:

```
protected void **service**(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

or:

```
protected void **doPost**(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

Html code side, usually setting the http method like get or post. For example:

```
<form action="CrunchifyServlet" method="POST">
```

But there is no specification of http method. Perhaps html communicates to server with get method and servlet can't get recognized.

Please add code like sysout in servlet. And there is no output, http method is suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

> unable to hit the index page successfully

Let us say that your index page contents are in a file named `index.html`. Follow the instructions given below:

1. Place `index.html` file in the root directory of the war file i.e, at the same level with the `WEB-INF` directory.
2. Package and deploy the app into the context `CrunchifyJSPServletExample`.
3. Finally call the URL **localhost:9080/CrunchifyJSPServletExample**. It should fetch the contents of `index.html`.